# Javascript клик внутри фрейма

Tags: javascript

как мне узнать что пользователь кликнул внутри фрейма, но определить только с главной страницы. там где стоит сам фрейм. возможно такое? onclick поставить не возможно в сам фрейм (тизерный фрейм)

Comment: Никак или запустить браузер без `origin police`, для Хрома это так:  

    --disable-web-security
Осталось просто убедить посетителя, что для просмотра этого сайта надо запустить браузер особым образом.

Comment: Ай яй яй... накрутчик. Тебя после этого ещё и в тизерной сети скорее всего забанят)))

Answer (score 1):

Если домен фрейма совпадает с доменом главной страницы, то так:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("irame").contentWindow.location.reload();
}
```

Или же как написал [[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus) - никак, кроме запуска в небезопасном режиме.